# expl3 and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, expl3

I would like to hold some text in a global variable, which i'm using as the content of a `tabular`. I'm using `expl3`, and `tikz` to place the `tabular`. The problem is that in an expl3 environment tikz is not working as expected.

Here after reading solutions to similar problems i got my code working.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>

\usepackage{tikz,tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \tl_tmpa
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycontent} { m }
   {
   \tl_clear:N \tl_tmpa
   \tl_put_right:Nn \tl_tmpa {
   \begin{tblr}{|l|}
   \hline
     #1
   \hline
   \end{tblr}
}
   \let\mytikznode\tl_tmpa
   }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\myframe} {}
{
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at (current page.north)
        [shift={(0,-4)}, anchor=north]{
          \mytikznode
        };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\mycontent{ a a a \\
         b b b \\}
\myframe
\end{document}
```

If I move the two statements `\begin{tblr}{|l|}` and `\end{tblr}` in `\myframe` and leave

```
\hline
#1
\hline
```

in `\mycontent` and not touching anything else, the build fails. Also without doing `\let\mytikznode\tl_tmpa` and using `\tl_tmpa` instead of `\mytikznode` in `\myframe` the build fails. I still don't see where is coming from the problem. I'm posting it to get some clarity and if possible get the code more concise.

Comment: You need to add the `expand` option to `\begin{tblr}` in this case to ensure that the things inside are expanded before `tabularray` parses it. So, change `\begin{tblr}{|l|}` to `\begin{tblr}[expand=\mytikznode]{|l|}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The deeper the nesting, the more cautious you need to be with expansion. In this case, you need to expand the contents of the `tblr` environment before it is being parsed. The `tabularray` package provides an `expand` option exactly for such cases (see section 3.2.3 Expand Macros First in the [`tabularray` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf)).

More concretely, in your case you would need to replace `\begin{tblr}{|l|}` by `\begin{tblr}[expand=\mytikznode]{|l|}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{tikz, tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \tl_tmpa
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycontent} { m } {
    \tl_clear:N \tl_tmpa
    \tl_put_right:Nn \tl_tmpa {
        \hline
            #1
        \hline
    }
    \let\mytikznode\tl_tmpa
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\myframe} {} {
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.north)
            [shift={(0,-4)}, anchor=north]{
            \begin{tblr}[expand=\mytikznode]{|l|}
                \mytikznode
            \end{tblr}
        };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\mycontent{ a a a \\
            b b b \\ }
\myframe
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Actually, you can simply stay in expl3 mode. There is no need to `\let\mytikznode\tl_tmpa` then (you only need to take care about spaces in Ti*k*Z options). Also, better adhere to the established naming conventions of the expl3 syntax:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usepackage{tikz, tabularray}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_userx_temp_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycontent} { m } {
    \tl_clear:N \l_userx_temp_tl
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_userx_temp_tl {
        \hline
            #1
        \hline
    } 
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\myframe} {} {
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember~picture,overlay]
            \node at (current~page.north)
                [shift={(0,-4)}, anchor=north]{
                \begin{tblr}[expand=\l_userx_temp_tl]{|l|}
                    \l_userx_temp_tl
                \end{tblr}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycontent{ a a a \\ 
            b b b \\ }
\myframe
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, it works. Do you know why we absolutely need to put `\let\mytikznode\tl_tmpa'? AFAIK '\let\b\a' is making '\b' useable exactly same as '\a'

Comment: @user1850133 You only need to do that if you want to take a macro that uses expl3 syntax for its name (especially an underscore) outside of the expl3 syntax scope. In your case, there is actually no need to do that. See my edit.

Comment: nice, you resolved the problem with `remember picture`. I initially did only one command, and as it failed i moved all `tikz` code to another function. Now the whole code can be a lot shorter.